# Real World measurements related to phonon dispersion

Tags: experimental-technique, phonons

I hope no one objects to the style of this question. Let me explain my motives in asking the question first.
Condensed matter physics is one of the most beautiful subjects around. But those who are trained as Theoretical Condensed Matter physicists tend to be abstracted away from the realities of labs and neutron diffraction measurements.
Which is why I wanted to do a section in my thesis where the theoretical output, in my case the Phononic Dispersion of a particular Material, is numerically obtained.
I would like to ask what other properties / measurables depend on the phonon dispersion relation (doesn't have to be exclusively dependent).
The ones I found out out myself are -

1. Thermal Conductivity/Specific Heat
2. Neutron Diffraction

You don't have to expand on the answers if you don't want to .. I will EDIT the list and put in descriptions myself.
The problem is that there cannot be ONE right answer to this. So I wouldn't be able to mark a certain answer as correct. All the same it is a valuable question to ask .. and I will curate the answers myself.

*bows*

Answer (score 0):

In my lab we measure the complex dielectric permittivity of thin film semi-conductors below 1 thz. The attenuation is due to phonons and is dispersive.  Is that the sort of thing you had in mind?